# ParallelDo with NotebookDirectory[]

Tags: front-end, parallelization

I have a main directory with subdirectories numbered (1, 2, 3, ...). In each folder there is an exe file. I execute this code:

```
ParallelDo[RunProcess[NotebookDirectory[] <> ToString[i] <> "\\main.exe", ProcessDirectory -> NotebookDirectory[] <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

And I get a bunch of errors: "A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end." and of course, the error mentioning that $Failed is not a string. I stripped the problem down to this: RunProcess is allright, what is problem is that ParallelDo can't process NotebookDirectory[]:

```
ParallelDo[Print[NotebookDirectory[] <> ToString[i] <> "\\main.exe"], {i, 1, 10}]
```

(same errors)

What is the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: The subkernels do not have a front end connected, so they do not know what is the NotebookDirectory[].  Assign the notebook directory to a variable and use that in ParallelDo.

Comment: Oh! That works and the solution is so trivial...Thank you!